# Expectation in phpunit test case

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I have index method

```
public function indexAction()
{

       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

       $entities = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Blog')->findAll();

       return array(
           'entities' => $entities,
       );
   }  // End of method
```

When I try to unit test case for this action like below

```
  public function testIndexAction()
   {

       $entityManager = $this->getMockBuilder('BlogController')
           ->disableOriginalConstructor()
           ->setMethods(array('getRepository'))
           ->getMock();

       $entityManager->expects($this->once())
           ->method('findAll')
           ->will($this->returnValue(0));    
   }  // End of method
```

It give me error below

> AppBundle\Tests\Controller\BlogController\BlogControllerTest::testIndexAction
>   Expectation failed for method name is equal to  when
>   invoked 1 time(s).

Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.

Comment: findAll is being called on the repository object not the entity manager.  Two completely different objects.

Answer (score 0):

$entityManager being built as a mock of `BlogController` (in the global namespace) does not make sense.

So it is perfectly logical that `BlogController::findAll` is not called.

Thus, your test is only creating mocks, but does not perform any action with them. so there is no reason for any method to be called.